# Should we merge "approximation" and "approximation-algorithms"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [approximation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation) is currently much more popular than the tag [approximation-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-algorithms), although both concern approximation algorithms. Should we get rid of the second?

Comment: Hmm, well what even are _approximation algorithms_? I have encountered different answers to the following statements: 1. An approximation algorithm gives a solution with a formal guarantee of the quality 2. An approximation algorithm always solves a _combinatorial_ problem 3. An approximation algorithm always solves an objective and well-defined optimisation problem... I think some of those answers are wrong, but they are nevertheless used by experts in certain CS fields. I'm not sure what I should conclude here, other that classifying these questions may be difficult.

Comment: (of course, here I haven't even touched on the difference between an _approximation algorithm_ and an algorithm that returns an "approximation" or "approximate solution".)

Comment: An approximation algorithm solves a combinatorial optimization problem with a worst-case guarantee on the approximation ratio.